# Cannot deserialize JSON when subclassing UIButton (JSON.NET)

Tags: ios, json, mono, xamarin.ios, json.net

I'm using json.net to parse some properties.
I was now trying to use it for a class which derives from UIButton:

```
    public class JsonButton : UIButton
{
    public String ItemId = "";
    
    public JsonButton ()
    {
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error:

> Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'MyApplication.JsonButton'.
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object existingValue) [0x003a4] in /Users/xxx/Projects/_MonoTouchLibraries/Newtonsoft.Json-master/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:441

The JSON is working without problems if i subclass it from my own class

```
public class JsonButton : MyOwnClass
{
    public String ItemId = "";
    
    public JsonButton ()
    {
    }
}
```

The test JSON is very simple (and as said working with the class above):

```
{
"ItemId": "16"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to deserialize something into a button? Maybe there is a better way to accomplish what you want without de/serializing buttons.
I'm sure that UIButton is a pretty complex object with properties and fields (possibly subclassed several level deep) that are required or even not serializable and this is what is causing problems for this.